# Moving window regression (MWR) in R?

Tags: r, modelling

I'm looking for some package in R to estimate the value of a variable by moving window regression. I have read in *Local Models for Spatial Analysis*, which is a good method to predict values ​​at unsampled locations. A very similar case is mentioned in the book, PRISM.

I've been reading various R packages, but have not found anything about MWR, GWR only.

Is there another way of naming or can GWR be adapted to function as MWR?

Text from book -> 
[Local Models for Spatial Analysis](http://books.google.es/books?id=Ej0q2DuBtXcC&lpg=PA122&ots=W8IaXdkS8v&dq=%22A%20simple%20way%20of%20assessing%20spatial%20variations%20in%20relations%20between%22&hl=es&pg=PA122#v=onepage&q=%22A%20simple%20way%20of%20assessing%20spatial%20variations%20in%20relations%20between%22&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any equations in the section in Lloyd that you linked to, but it seems from the description that MWR is similar to GWR except that it's on a grid (always, or just in this example?), and that it always uses a fixed bandwidth and a fixed or inverse-distance weighted kernel. If this is correct, I think you can accomplish what you want by using GWR and specifying the weighting function yourself instead of using the built-in functions (gwr.gauss, gwr. bilinear).

In the gwr function call, set the `bandwidth` argument to the desired radius of the moving window, in the units of your spatial object (will depend on the projection), and set the `gweight` argument as follows:

```
gwr(..., gweight = function(a, b) 1, ...)
```

This function will return a weight of 1 for all point pairs in the local regressions, which is the simplest version described in source you linked to. (Note that `a` and `b` are arbitrary parameter names, internally gwr uses `dxs` for the first (distance) parameter and `bandwidthR2` for the second (bandwidth) parameter.) Make sure to specify the `fit.points` argument using a SpatialPointsDataFrame (or other object of xy coordinates) of the points that you want to predict. If your data is gridded, you will also have to convert to a SpatialPointsDataFrame for the data argument. This can be accomplished with:

```
gridded(yourGrid) = FALSE
```

This works for SpatialGridDataFrame or SpatialPixelsDataFrame, you may have to do something different if you're using the raster package.